# how to rotate Texture2D in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, rotation, texture2d

I'm making a game using cocos2d-iphone, I want's to rotate a Texture2D of maybe 20 degrees, what can I do?

I tried `glRotate(20.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)`, but it doesn't work.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the CCSprite property `rotation`

```
CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
sprite.position = ccp(100,100);
sprite.rotation = 20;
[scene addChild:sprite];
```

Comment: Yep, use it as a CCSprite is probably the easiest way.